# I want add scroll view behind half of the button

Tags: android

Please help me two add the scroll view behind the button (i.e) scrolling starting from the half button on wards please help me how to design

Comment: can you draw it? it's a bit confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,scroll view is from half way from button to onwards, lot of TextView are for checking scroll View.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge 
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text
                Large TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge TextLarge Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:background="#ffff55"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: here one issue is there the button is click able

Comment: you can write in class button.setClickable(false);